# URL rewriting, same URL across multiple PHP files

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Hey so I have create a login system to a website and I wish to have this login appear when I type in my address. When I have typed in details and logged in, I wish to be redirected to another PHP file, but with the same address.... this way, All I need to do is type in my address if I am allready logged in and I will go to the site which requires login.
I have made a transaction happen identifing if the session is created, if it is, it redirects me to another page, but also to another URL. I tried googleing it, but couldn't find anything exact and straight forward.

*Currently:*

**Login page:**
www.example.com

**Member page:**
www.example.com/members

*What I wish for:*

**Login page:**
www.example.com

**Member page:**
www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program structure should look like this.

**index.php**

```
if (user is logged in)
   display dashoard
else 
   display login page
```

Since you are using PHP, make use of [session functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php). Thus, URL rewriting is no longer necessary.

### Update

Assuming if you have file structure in PHP like this:

```
- index.php
- login.php  
+ template   
  - login.php
  - dashboard.php
```

You can do the following structure in `index.php` file.

```
define('IN_FILE', true);
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   require 'template/dashboard.php';
} else {
   require 'template/login.php';
}
```

In `template/dashboard.php`

```
if (!defined('IN_FILE')) {
   exit;
}

// Then your HTML, PHP and whatnot
```

And in `login.php`

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   require 'template/login.php';
} else {
   header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Change the code according to your needs.

Comment: I dont wish to make the design visible by putting everything into a index.php file... Thats the reason why I wish to use 2 files... I checked facebook and they have managed to keep 1 URL across the login and when you are logged in. How can I do this? Also, I use session functions, but my URL changes when I use if statements that brings me to the members.php from index.php

Comment: Ahem, you forgot your opening and closing `{ }` *grin*

Comment: @FrieBitz, how about using `required` or `include` function? You don't have to put it everything.

Comment: @WindShear I know, I was just kidding 'round ;-) Humour helps at this time of night.

Comment: @Fred, yeah didn't see that * sheepish *

Comment: Will include and require keep the same URL? but make it possible to design from a second file?

Comment: @FriedBlitx. Yes it does keep it to the same URL. See my updated answer.

Comment: `@ALL` - Keep in mind to have `session_start();` at the top of every file, *if and when* using sessions. This is the biggest mistake that people make.

Comment: Okai, so the index file is simply a redirecting to the two other files? dashboard and the login file? by using if statements for session and the inside put require whatever site directing to?

Comment: @FriedBitz, read and understand how the [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function and [`require`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) function works.

Comment: I partly understand them but will read more on them :) Thanks

Comment: Ehmmm, may I ask, should I put the files within a subfolder or keep them in the same folder as the index file?

Comment: @FriedBitz, it's up to you where you may put the files. The important thing is the path is correct.

Comment: Okai, so I get the index.php still, how can I prevent this from appearing? (in the members.php that is)

Comment: and also, my website can log in twice, once by using the `www.example.com` and once by just typing `example.com`... it creates 2 instances...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using several approaches.

a) Use session to determine the current page, so if a user click on a link, create a session store the value and on page load read the session data and include the file accordingly.

b) Use URL parameter to determine the page (this is the most common approach). for example in index.php you can add more parameters like `index.php?page=somepage` and by reading the value using `$_GET` and including the PHP file accordingly.

There are some more way to achieve what you want to, for instance using javascript/jQuery this is possible.